# Citrus Framework: I am getting NoSuchBeanDefinitionException for testing JMS sample provided by Christopher

Tags: java, citrus-framework

I am new to Citrus framework.

I am getting the following errors:

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'helloServiceEndpoint' available
```

I am trying to use Citrus for a project I am working on. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please kind of urgent for me and any help will be appreciated. Currently I can't Test JMS Message to Topics using Citrus Framework. 
I will Love to use Citrus framework for this project than any other tool. because I seems to love it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` tells me that you are using a Citrus endpoint component named `helloServiceEndpoint` in your test case and this component is missing in your Spring application context configuration.

You need to define a Citrus endpoint named `helloServiceEndpoint` either in XML e.g. `citrus-context.xml` or in any Java Spring bean configuration class as `@Bean` annotated method definition.

Please review your Spring bean configuration and the concrete bean naming in your test and configuration.